# Android ListView style issue with background while scroll

Tags: android, android-widget

I need to style ListView and can't figure out why It turns to black background when scroll.. I have ListView inside LinearLayout and that layout has Background set to image.

This is what I have for ListView:

```
<style name="MyListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selector_list_item</item>
    </style>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/shape_list_item_normal" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/shape_list_item_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/shape_list_item_normal" />
</selector>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#80ffffff" android:endColor="#80eff3ef" android:angle="45" />
    <padding android:left="5dip" android:right="5dip" android:top="7dip" android:bottom="7dip"/>
</shape>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="#80808080" android:endColor="#80eff3ef" android:angle="45" />
    <padding android:left="5dip" android:right="5dip" android:top="7dip" android:bottom="7dip"/>
</shape>
```

When I apply MyListView style I don't see much happening. When I click on item - yes, I see gradient. When ListView stable - I see background as it should be from parent layout. When I scroll - I see black background, it's erasing parent's background. And I would be fine with that if I knew how to set it with something else..

Answer (score 8):

Use the following property in the xml of listView:

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this line of code in the xml of your listview:

android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 0):

If you require transparent `ListView` in a `PreferenceActivity`, try using a theme with

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyPreferencesTheme">
        <item name="android:scrollingCache">false</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And put the theme in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity 
    android:name="YourActivity" 
    android:theme="@style/MyPreferencesTheme">
</activity>
```